# Line is not drawn from a textblock to another textblock that is within another canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, wpf-controls

```
 <StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Line StrokeDashArray="4 4" Stroke="Red" X1="0" Y1="0" X2="{Binding LeftPoint}" Y2="{Binding TopPoint}"></Line>
        <TextBlock Text="Hello"></TextBlock>
    <Border Height="100"></Border>
    <Canvas Name="B" >
        <Border Height="48"></Border>
        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding LeftPoint, Mode=TwoWay}"  Canvas.Top="{Binding TopPoint, Mode=TwoWay}" Text="World"></TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Above is the code sample, line is not drawn from hello to world. I would like to preserve the structure and still be able to draw the line.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the `StrokeThickness`:

```
 <Line StrokeDashArray="4 4" 
       Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="1"
       X1="0" X2="{Binding LeftPoint}"
       Y1="0" Y2="{Binding TopPoint}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. No, that is not just the case. Breakpoints do not get hit at all for LeftPoint and TopPoint.